# Get and set height from multiple iFrames with the same ID

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm fitting iframe height like this:

```
      // Fit height for iframe
      // Create IE + others compatible event handler
      var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
      var eventer = window[eventMethod];
      var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";



      // Listen to message from child window
      eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
           document.getElementById('frame-'+e.data.id+'').style.height = e.data.height + 'px';
      }, false);
```

and it's working very well as it is. I have 3 iframes on the page and all have different id (that I got from e.data.id), but problem is when I add another one iframe with same source but have different parameters, in that case I have two same ids with different height and just first one get it's height.

How I can adjust this in order to each iframe get it's own height no matter the id, or somehow else to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of targeting `id`, you can just match `source`, e.g.:

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
  if (iframes[i].contentWindow === e.source) {
    iframes[i].style.height = e.data.height + "px";
    break;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could look into `MessageChannel` to give each `iframe` its own unique messaging channel, in which case you will always know which iframe the message has come from due to the channel the message was received on.

However, a note on security - you ought to be checking the `origin` (and potentially other checks) of the incoming messages. You wouldn't want unauthorised iframes sending you messages with data in them that then leads to you manipulating elements of the page in potentially malicious ways.